# adding constraints to a spinner in my code

Tags: android, constraints, spinner

I have a code in my app which when you click the FAB, a spinner appears. when I test this on my phone which is quite small in screen size, the spinner shows up right. but when I try it on a bigger phone screen size, the spinner seems to shrink and is hidden partially.

Is it possible to add constraints to my code here so that the size of the spinner will change depending on the size of the screen and it won't be partially cut off/hidden?

code:

```
SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner); //Add another spinner


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins( 5,  130,  10,  0);
                layoutParams.height = 80;//pixels
                layoutParams.width = 240;//pixels
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Try to set it using *dimens* for different *values* folder and set that *dimen*  *progrmatically*. And you can then check for multi resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your spinner have a consistent size/looks on different screen sizes you have to use DP(density independent pixels) instead of simple pixels.

What I would recommend you to do is to set your layout.height/width to specific DP by converting DP to pixels using this:

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}
```

---

Good luck :)

Comment: :D Thank you :) But when I use that code , the 'context' goes red?

Comment: you are using it in activity or fragment?

Comment: I put it in my activity under onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) . what is fragment?

Comment: If you use this function in activity then delete `Context context` from function parameters and use only `getResources();` instead of `context.getResources()`

Comment: thanks, but for the return px; it says 'cannot return  a value from a method with void result type'

Comment: use `public float` instead of `public void`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177698/discussion-between-tomas-jablonskis-and-crazycodern).